# Restarting UITableView issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5, storyboard

I have a UITableView not created in the storyboard but by code. This table can be refreshed by selecting some other champs but when I do that there is another table with the old data... I set to nil very time I refresh...

Somebody has an idea??

To fill the table I use this code

```
listVideo = [listGroupes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
montageListView= [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:listFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
montageListView.delegate = self;
montageListView.dataSource = self;
montageListView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
[listMontagesView addSubview:montageListView];
```

so there is a new view with another options but if I go back with this code:

```
montagesListView removeFromSuperview];
montagesListView = nil;
```

and I Refill it with the same code

```
listVideo = [listGroupes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
montageListView= [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:listFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
montageListView.delegate = self;
montageListView.dataSource = self;
montageListView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
[listMontagesView addSubview:montageListView];
```

and there is the good table but there is another with the old data...
I really don't find a problem with code :/

Here is the code of cell for row, but I don't think this is the problem,

```
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
NSString *text;
// Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

// If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
if (cell == nil) {
    // Use the default cell style.
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == groupListView) {
    text = [listGroupesNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else {

    text = [[listVideo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]description];
    if ([[listVideo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]note] == 1) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"good.png"];
    }
    if ([[listVideo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]note] == 2) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"neutre.png"];
    }
    if ([[listVideo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]note] == 3) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bad.png"];
    }
}

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
    text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"           %@",text];
}else{
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
}
if (tableView == groupListView) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"group.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
if(tableView == montageListView){
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"videos.png"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = text;
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is impossible to tell exactly what the problem is, but if you are recreating the table view every time then you need to make sure you do `[tableView removeFromSuperview]` prior to setting it to nil.

Comment: Yes i do that so i remove it from superview and then I am restarting it so there is the new table filled correctly but behind it there is the old one... it doesnt get the touch events but it is there...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to understand but here's my take on it.

It seems that you want to refresh the data 'inside' the table view? If so, you don't need to create a new UITableView. Just call `reloadData` and the UITableView will query it's delegate and datasource for the new data.

If you add a new UITableView instance but return the same data in the datasource and delegate methods, it will just display the old data. Make sure you update the methods.

Comment: I had the reload data and it made the same, is there a second table with the old data, I can't post images so you see the issue, Pd: Im sorry for my english XD

Comment: Did you update the delegate and datasource methods to return the new data?

Comment: Could you please post your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` code.

Comment: the curious thing is that when there are two tables, the old one doesn't react to the events of did check row and if I make it descend the cells dissapear...

Comment: Well, it's no use recreating whole UITableView if you just want to display other data. You should just call `reloadData` and the delegate and datasource should handle the rest. If this doesn't work, there must be some problem in these delegate and datasource methods. I can't say what the exact problem is without seeing the whole code though.